# Rails 4 - How to disable dragging in 'panzoom'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In rails 4.2.2, I am using `panzoom` jquery for zooming feature, I need to disable the drag option which is happening while checking it. An image or any element which is inside the `div.panzoom` should be static (should not move).

Referred by http://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/jQuery-Plugin-For-Panning-Zooming-Any-Elements-panzoom.html

In View file,

```
<div id="html_view">
  <div class="panzoom" style="height: 480px;">
    <%= render :file => @path %>
  </div>
</div>

$(".panzoom").panzoom({
  $zoomIn:    $(".zoom-in"),
  $zoomOut:   $(".zoom-out"),
  $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
  $reset:     $(".reset", false)
});
```

Please help me solve dragging issue.

Comment: I have updated the question. Here, I am using html elements instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".panzoom").panzoom({
  $zoomIn:    $(".zoom-in"),
  $zoomOut:   $(".zoom-out"),
  $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range"),
  $reset:     $(".reset", false),
  $(this).( 'option', 'transition', false )
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: Last line `$(this).( 'option', 'transition', false )`